# Disinterested vs. uninterested

Tags: differences, word-usage

I’ve always understood the difference between *disinterested* and *uninterested* as follows:

- *uninterested*: not interested, not up to it
- *disinterested*: impartial

Consider the situation of someone unwilling to help another in need. Is that person uninterested or disinterested?

I’d always thought it has to be *uninterested*, but I’ve read *disinterested* used in contexts like the one just given.

Comment: They are synonyms of each other, hence used interchangeably.

Comment: @Invoker [Grammar Girl](http://www.quickanddirtytips.com/education/grammar/disinterested-versus-uninterested) disagrees: An uninterested person is bored, unconcerned, or indifferent; a disinterested person is impartial, unbiased, or has no stake in the outcome. If you're on trial, you want a disinterested judge. Unless you're a lawyer, the word you're generally looking for is "uninterested," but a quick news search shows that "disinterested" is frequently misused by the media. Here's how to use them properly: - Squiggly couldn't help yawning; he was uninterested in fishing stories.

Comment: A quick search on google also listed uninterested as a synonym of disinterested. The case you stated is a cut-out case and I suppose in majority of the cases, using either one of the above does not ask for rectification.

Comment: @Invoker - If you Google "disinterested versus uninterested" you will get a bunch of links showing that in the standard dialect (i.e., the one used for international scientific communication, etc.) the words have distinct meanings. Only two of the top 5 links for the search "disinterested synonym uninterested" say that they are synonymous (and one of those has a clear caveat).

Comment: @Invoker Yes, in fact all words can be used interchangeably, if you don't care about being understood.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You're right about the meaning of disinterested. It's *impartial*, *unbiased*, or *having no stake in the outcome*.

If you're uninterested, you're *bored*, *unconcerned*, or *indifferent*. Here's [Grammar Girl explaining the differences](http://www.quickanddirtytips.com/education/grammar/disinterested-versus-uninterested), if that's helpful.

If you see someone in need and you are not interested in helping them, it is very likely that you are uninterested in helping them, not disinterested. But I think the similarity between the prefixes dis- and un- is what causes people to treat them so interchangeably.

If you look at [their meanings](http://www.dailywritingtips.com/the-difference-between-un-and-dis/), you'll get a better idea as to why disinterested and uninterested are so different yet similar. Basically dis- is used in separation cases, but un- is used for a reversal of an action. It isn't apparent in all cases, but it should help you see why it's so easy to say "uninterested" instead of "disinterested".

Comment: Thanks for suggesting why people get them mixed up. Majority of my American friends use disinterested in a wrong way. So I was a little confused as I'm not a native english speaker.

Comment: Using *disinterested* when *uninterested* is meant is a very common error (I say error here because a useful distinction in the standard dialect is elided when the words are not distinguished).